# How can i fix my checkbox click in Selenium Webdriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox

I am using Selenium in Java to test the checking of a checkbox in a webapp. Here's my code:

```
WebElement checkBox1;
checkBox1 = driver.findElement((By.xpath(xpathOfElement)));
checkBox1.click();
```

The Selenium Webdriver find the checkbox's position, but for some reason it does not click on. Only checkbox's area becomes gray, but the checkbox will not be active.

Here is relevant parts of my HTML:

```
<div id="componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:sbc" class="ui-chkbox ui-widget" style="position:relative; top:5px;">
  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <input id="componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:sbc_input" type="checkbox" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:"componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:sbc",e:"change",f:"newApplicationForm",p:"componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:sbc",u:"componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:wrapper",ps:true});" aria-checked="true" name="componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:sbc_input">
  </div>
  <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active">
    <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-check"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this problem in Selenium WebDriver with Java? Will be grateful for any help.

Active checkbox HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active"> 
  <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-c"></span> 
</div>
```

Inactive checkbox HTML looks like this

```
<div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"> 
  <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-blank"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share xpath for that element ?

Comment: Sure.
`xpath1 = "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div/fieldset/div/div[1]/div[2]/span";`

Comment: I think this is not a way to write xpath. Because you will surely get No such Element exception while any element is changed by developers.

Comment: can you check and uncheck the checkbox manually and post the html each time? I think the "status" of the checkbox will be a change within the attributes of the div-element, let's see

Comment: Active checkbox

`<div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active">
<span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-c"></span>
</div>`
Inactive checkbox

`<div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
<span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-blank"></span>
</div>`

Comment: you should provide relevant html code and your xpathToElement, there can be several bugs and please edit your question accordingly

Comment: I tried whitout `/span`, but it does not work.

Comment: I have given one solution. Please refer it. If it is not helpful Let me know.

Comment: I guess you somehow need to give a link to the WHOLE html, maybe there is an iframe or something because with your snippets my solution does work locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem, thank you all for your help.

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebElement element = driver.findElement((By.xpath(xpathOfElement)));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Actions:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(xpathOfElement).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Others might benefit from an explanation as to why this code is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the source-code you provided, you can directly search for the input elements.

Since all your relevant input-elements have the same id, you need to ask for the "2nd" using "[2]" at the end of your xpath-query:

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'ui-helper-hidden-accessible']/input[contains(@id, 'componentIndicators:1')]"));
checkBox.click();
```

Comment: I have five checkbox with same attribute and the webdriver can find the element.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/6mtB5Uq4), I want to locate and click the second checkbox.

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[contains(@id, 'componentIndicators:1')][2]"}

Comment: @Milky, sorry forgot the braces, edited answer try again!

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//input[contains(@id, 'componentIndicators:1')])[2]"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90617/discussion-between-drkthng-and-milky).

Answer (score 0):

- I suggest you to use xpath in that way , Like it is never give no such element exception. It is also not confusing for you to regenerate or identify same xpath.
- If it is possible , Please always use CSSPath.
- As per your HTML code use this xpath or csspath.

CSS path :

```
".ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-blank"
```

or

```
 "span[class='ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-blank']"
```

---

XPATH :

```
//span[@class='ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-blank']
```

or

```
//span[contains(@class,'ui-chkbox-icon')]
```

Now you can use this element to click.

For more info about xpath [Please Refer This Link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp).

For CSS path [Please Refer This Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

============================================================

One more problem is that you have may be same attribute for all the checkbox.

Here is solution Please refer links which I have given and made Custom Xpath as Under :

```
(//span[contains(@class,'ui-chkbox-icon')])[1]
```

Here give count as 1, 2, 3 .. till your check box all elements are not taken by you.Now you have all different element.

Comment: I have five checkbox with same attribute and the webdriver can find the element based on xpath. I watched this with one branch.
  `isChecked = driver
    .findElement(
      (By.xpath(xpath1)))
    .getAttribute("class");if (!isChecked.contains("ui-state-active")) {...}`

Comment: InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[contains(@class,'ui-chkbox-icon')])[1] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: You missed ( in starting

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can click this customised checkbox of yours in any way. Can you try adding the active-state class dynamically using javascript and see if it works. Here's how -

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:sbc').getElementsByTagName('div')[1].className += 'ui-state-active';");
```

The above code will set the class active to the div. Now if you have more div's with id - `componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:sbc` then use the array index for it too. Here's how -

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementsById('componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:sbc')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[1].className += 'ui-state-active';");
//Replace index 0 with your element's index value. Note, its a zero based index
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got the same phenomenon, checkbox's area becomes gray, but the checkbox will not be active